# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\src\.cpp:660: error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, object, cvlib

My code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
import tensorflow as tf

im = cv2.imread('road.PNG')
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\divin\Wk5_Lab_McGrath_Anthony\LAB9-object_detection.py", line 8, in <module>
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\divin\Wk5_Lab_McGrath_Anthony\venv\Lib\site-packages\cvlib\object_detection.py", line 125, in detect_common_objects
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights_file_abs_path, config_file_abs_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:660: error: (-215:Assertion failed) separator_index < line.size() in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

I am unsure how to decipher the error given.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the image is not loaded correctly (image location is wrong).

Give the address like:

```
"C:\\Users\\divin\\Wk5_Lab_McGrath_Anthony\\LAB9-object_detection.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have corrupted files in C:\Users\USER\ .cvlib\object_detection\yolo\yolov3

Delete this (C:\Users\USER\ .cvlib) folder;
Correct files will be downloaded automatically.